# date problems in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to assign the `$datestring` to the **DAY** of the **WEEK** - eg. *Sunday*, *Monday* etc., because the value of `%w` is numeric - which means 1 is monday , 2 is tues etc.

This is a codeignitor project and my code runs the first conditional statement whether it's true or false!  Please help.

```
     public function data()
 {

$datestring = "%w";
$time = time();

 echo mdate($datestring, $time);


if ($datastring =  "1") {

  echo "monday";
}
else if ($datastring = "2") {

  echo "tuesday";
}
 else if ($datastring = "3") {

  echo "wednesday";
}     

else if ($datastring = "4") {

  echo "thursday";
}

else if ($datastring = "5") {

  echo "friday";
}
else if ($datastring = "6") {

  echo "saturday";
}

else if ($datastring = "7") {

  echo "sunday";
}
return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare you need double `==`, because `=` is an assigned. And assign "1" to variable $datastring is always true, so always first if is true. Change it to:

```
if ($datastring ==  "1") {

  echo "monday";
}
else if ($datastring == "2") {

  echo "tuesday";
}
 else if ($datastring == "3") {

  echo "wednesday";
}     

else if ($datastring == "4") {

  echo "thursday";
}

else if ($datastring == "5") {

  echo "friday";
}
else if ($datastring == "6") {

  echo "saturday";
}
else if ($datastring == "7") {

  echo "sunday";
}
```

Edit: I also added an `else if`statement for sunday. You can use a simple `else` on this too because no other options are left (as far as $datastring can only content the numbers 1 to seven.

To make it more cleaner I would use `switch` like

```
switch ($datastring) {

  case 1:
    $day = "monday";
    break;
  case 2:
    $day = "tuesday";
    break;
  case 3:
    $day = "wednesday";
    break;
  case 4:
    $day = "thursday";
    break;
  case 5:
    $day = "friday";
    break;
  case 6:
    $day = "saturday";
    break;
  case 7:
    $day = "sunday";
    break;
  default:
    $day = "unknown day";
    break;    
}

echo $day;
```

Comment: Thank you . The switch worked perfect. I was never sure when to use switch in programing . well now i know one way.

Comment: Your welcome. If it was useful to you please vote it up and accept it to show the community that it help you with your problem. Have a nice day!

Comment: i can only vote it up when ive earn 15 reputation , it says .